# Regexp_substr to extract after certain set of characters Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Hello I want only 1 expression to fulfill all the 3 below criteria.String will will always start with `CALL` or `(`

Will `Replace` work better or `Substr`

1) pick 4 characters after )

2) pick 4 characters after RX:

3) pick 4 characters before PASS
For example :

```
CALL RX: W234    =>W234
(S123) T123 #100 =>T123
CALL Y123 PASS   =>Y123
CALL Q12  PASS   =>Q12
```

I tried I tried Replace `REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'CALL (RX:)?|PASS|\(.*\)|[[:punct:]].*')`. But it is not extracting LXC2 for this string (D123) LXC2 99

Comment: OK.  Great.  What have you attempted?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I tried Replace REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'CALL (RX:)?|PASS|\(.*\)|[[:punct:]].*'). But it is not extracting LXC2 for this string (D123) LXC2 99

Comment: @OldProgrammer I tried the above regexp_replace (edited in the question) but is there something less complex and also fit any variations that may arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner.  The Common Table Expression (the with clause) just sets up the data set for example's sake:

```
with tbl(idx, data) as (
  select 1, 'CALL RX: W234' from dual union all
  select 2, '(S123) T123 #100' from dual union all
  select 3, 'CALL Y123 PASS' from dual union all
  select 4, 'CALL Q12  PASS' from dual union all
  select 5, '(D123) LXC2 99' from dual
) 
select idx, 
  regexp_substr(data, '^(CALL|\(.*?\)) (RX: )?(.*?)( |PASS|$)', 1, 1, null, 3) result
from tbl;


       IDX RESULT          
---------- ----------------
         1 W234            
         2 T123            
         3 Y123            
         4 Q12             
         5 LXC2            

5 rows selected.
```

It uses groups to match lines starting with `'CALL'` or a set of any characters inside of parenthesis followed by a space, then an optional string of `'RX:`'.  The next set of characters that are followed by a group of either a space, string of `'PASS'` or the end of the line are captured non-greedily.  This happens to be the third group, which is returned by the 6th argument.

Note this works with the sample data set you provided.  If you have different examples, you may need to do some tweaking of the regex.

Comment: Wow!! thats so cool.. yep it worked perfectly for all the cases!.You are the MAN! Thanks again for your time and effort. I will have to understand the non-greedy part.Thank you so much! Appreciate your talent

Comment: @RajA It is unneeded with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for extracting the string between two spaces. So consider using `[[:space:]]` `POSIX` regular expression with `regexp_substr()`, and `regexp_count()` and `replace()` as auxiliary :

```
with t(text) as
(                  
 select '(D123) LXC2 99'   from dual union all
 select 'CALL RX: W234'    from dual union all
 select '(S123) T123 #100' from dual union all
 select 'CALL Y123 PASS'   from dual 
), t2(text) as
(
 select replace(text,'CALL RX:','') from t
)
 select case when regexp_count(text,'[[:space:]]') >= 2 then 
             regexp_substr( text,'[[:space:]](.*)[[:space:]]') 
        else
             text
        end as "Result"
   from t2;

Result
------
LXC2
W234  
T123
Y123
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffd522dfff395fa2eb9cd986563956f2)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot Barbaros,but I need W234 instead of RX: for the 2nd row.

Comment: Again Many thanks for your prompt help. But Barbaros, I was looking for a single expression as this has to be applied at many places.The problem is I  cannot create a function where I would have love to put this logic in.But thanks a lot again.If you think a single expression is possible please do let me know.Appreciate your help very  much!

Comment: OK, thank you too @RajA , but you can create a function also by using this query and by sending your special string such as `CALL RX:` as a parameter for that function.